# Grails URL Mapping maps to wrong url

Tags: grails, url-mapping

Grails 1.3.5

When mapping to a new controller in my application:

```
"/order/$action/$id?" {
  controller = "customerOrder"
}
```

the request for "/order/show/13" resolves to "/(*)/(*)?/(*)?" as seen here in the log:

```
17:53:02 DEBUG  UrlMappingsFilter - Matched URI [/order/show/13] to URL mapping [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?], forwarding to [/grails/home/page.dispatch] with response [class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsContentBufferingResponse]
```

If I add this mapping:

```
"/order/show/13"{
  controller = "customerOrder"
  action = "show"
  id = 13
}
```

It still resolves to "/(*)/(*)?/(*)?". I edited the mapping:

```
"/customerOrder/show/13"{
  controller = "customerOrder"
  action = "show"
  id = 13
}
```

and the log reports:

```
18:50:08 DEBUG  DefaultUrlMappingsHolder - Matched URI [/customerOrder/show/13] with pattern [/customerOrder/show/13], adding to posibilities
```

Later it also reports:

```
18:50:08 DEBUG  DefaultUrlMappingsHolder - Matched URI [/customerOrder/show/13] with pattern [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?], adding to posibilities
```

I'm totally baffled on this one. Either way, it resolves the same. Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, in 1.3.5, you have to use a named closure intstead of the function syntax when declaring a view function.

```
def show( Long id ) { }
```

versus

```
def show = {}
```

The latter is correct. If someone could shed some light as to why...